# Comparing the values in the same position of two equal length data.frames in R

Tags: r

I am new to R so I am not sure if a similar Question has already been asked, but searching did not give me the answer I needed.

Having two kind of data.frames with the same number of columns(321) and rows(281) ordered by latitude and longitude. DF1("Laender") contains the German states as characters. It looks this way:

```
lat\lon   ...  8.70         8.75         8.80    ...
...        
51.30          Hessen       Hessen       Hessen
51.25          NRWestfalen  Hessen       Hessen
51.20          NRWestfalen  NRWestfalen  Hessen
51.15          NRWestfalen  Hessen       Hessen
...
```

DF2("df") contains values, ordered the same way. I have different DF2s for every hour of the year and need to get the mean values for every German state. It does work the following way:

```
Laender <- read.csv("path/file.csv", row.names = 1, check.names = F)
df <- read.csv("path/file1.csv", row.names = 1, check.names = F)

#  XXtot <- 0 creating the needed variables

for(i in 1:321){
  for(j in 1:281){
    BYtot <- ifelse(Laender[i,j]=="Bayern", BYtot + df[i,j], BYtot)
    SDtot <- ifelse(Laender[i,j]=="Saarland", SDtot + df[i,j], SDtot)
    BWtot <- ifelse(Laender[i,j]=="BadenW", BWtot + df[i,j], BWtot)
    STtot <- ifelse(Laender[i,j]=="SAnhalt", STtot + df[i,j], STtot)
    SNtot <- ifelse(Laender[i,j]=="Sachsen", SNtot + df[i,j], SNtot)
    MVtot <- ifelse(Laender[i,j]=="MVorpommern", MVtot + df[i,j], MVtot)
    NRWtot <- ifelse(Laender[i,j]=="NRWestfalen", NRWtot + df[i,j], NRWtot)
    BEtot <- ifelse(Laender[i,j]=="Berlin", BEtot + df[i,j], BEtot)
    HHtot <- ifelse(Laender[i,j]=="Hamburg", HHtot + df[i,j], HHtot)
    HBtot <- ifelse(Laender[i,j]=="Bremen", HBtot + df[i,j], HBtot)
    SHtot <- ifelse(Laender[i,j]=="SHolstein", SHtot + df[i,j], SHtot)
    NStot <- ifelse(Laender[i,j]=="Niedersachsen", NStot + df[i,j], NStot)
    HEtot <- ifelse(Laender[i,j]=="Hessen", HEtot + df[i,j], HEtot)
    THtot <- ifelse(Laender[i,j]=="Thueringen", THtot + df[i,j], THtot)
    RPtot <- ifelse(Laender[i,j]=="RPfalz", RPtot + df[i,j], RPtot)
    BRtot <- ifelse(Laender[i,j]=="Brandenburg", BRtot + df[i,j], BRtot)
  }
}
```

This will give me the total values for every German state and I can calculate the mean value after this, but it takes way too long since I have to do the procedure with all 8760 versions of DF2.

I hope there is an easier and faster way to do this.

Comment: Can you provide more information on the contents of those DF2s? Maybe show the result of `str(DF2)` for one of them?

Comment: If your `dfs` are of equal lengths you can run numerous row-by-row [comparisons](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Manipulating_data/Comparing_data_frames/). It seems like there are two elements to your questions, one concerned with efficient way of comparing data frames and the other one concerned with efficient way of obtaining summary statistics. Presumably, it would be a matter of using `dplyr` or `aggregate` to more efficiently obtain some of the desired measures but it's difficult to say without looking at a sample data and reproducible example.

Comment: The DF2s look exactly like "Laender" but have numeric values instead of characters:
'data.frame': 321 obs. of  281 variables:
 $ V30 : int  0 1 1 7 5 5 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ V31 : int  0 2 2 3 5 2 1 0 0 0 ...
 $ V32 : int  0 1 1 3 2 2 1 0 0 0 ...
 $ V33 : int  0 1 1 3 4 4 1 0 0 0 ...
 $ V34 : int  0 1 0 0 4 4 2 0 0 0 ...
 $ V35 : int  0 0 0 0 24 24 1 0 0 0 ...
 $ V36 : int  0 0 0 0 30 30 1 0 0 0 ...
 $ V37 : int  0 0 0 0 30 8 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ V38 : int  0 0 0 0 8 5 9 0 0 0 ...
 $ V39 : int  0 1 0 0 5 5 10 0 0 0 ...
 $ V40 : int  0 0 0 0 3 10 10 0 0 0 ...
...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what [`tapply()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/tapply.html) is designed for. Here's a demo using randomized data (so the lat/lon positions and state names won't correspond to reality):

```
states <- c('Bayern','Saarland','BadenW','SAnhalt','Sachsen','MVorpommern','NRWestfalen','Berlin','Hamburg','Bremen','SHolstein','Niedersachsen','Hessen','Thueringen','RPfalz','Brandenburg');
lats <- seq(51.30,by=-0.05,len=281);
lons <- seq(8.70,by=0.05,len=321);
set.seed(1);
Laender <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(states,length(lats)*length(lons),replace=T),length(lats),dimnames=list(sprintf('%.2f',lats),sprintf('%.2f',lons))));
df <- as.data.frame(matrix(pmax(0,round(rnorm(length(lats)*length(lons),5,20))),length(lats),dimnames=list(sprintf('%.2f',lats),sprintf('%.2f',lons))));
Laender[1:6,1:6];
##              8.70        8.75          8.80          8.85        8.90     8.95
## 51.30     Sachsen     Hamburg   MVorpommern        Berlin      Hessen   Hessen
## 51.25 MVorpommern      RPfalz Niedersachsen        Berlin      RPfalz   Berlin
## 51.20      Bremen MVorpommern        RPfalz   NRWestfalen     Sachsen   Bayern
## 51.15      RPfalz      Bayern Niedersachsen        Bayern      Berlin   BadenW
## 51.10     SAnhalt      BadenW       SAnhalt     SHolstein     Sachsen   BadenW
## 51.05      RPfalz MVorpommern     SHolstein Niedersachsen MVorpommern Saarland
df[1:6,1:6];
##       8.70 8.75 8.80 8.85 8.90 8.95
## 51.30   16    1    0   14    0    5
## 51.25   24    0   11    0   27    0
## 51.20   15    0    0   13    0   25
## 51.15    0   21    0   21    2    0
## 51.10   30    0    0   15    0    0
## 51.05    0    0    0   31    0    0
tapply(as.matrix(df),as.matrix(Laender),mean);
##        BadenW        Bayern        Berlin   Brandenburg        Bremen
##      10.35327      10.30455      10.80498      11.09401      10.57423
##       Hamburg        Hessen   MVorpommern Niedersachsen   NRWestfalen
##      11.05088      10.55788      10.66969      10.90239      11.09304
##        RPfalz      Saarland       Sachsen       SAnhalt     SHolstein
##      10.54924      10.48975      10.87170      10.49251      10.51719
##    Thueringen
##      10.52608
```

I would also recommend coercing to matrix immediately after reading in the data from CSV, since these tables are really more appropriate for the matrix type than the data.frame type. This is because you don't have heterogeneous columns; all columns and column types are homogeneous, which is characteristic of a matrix. I would just wrap your `read.csv()` calls in `as.matrix()`:

```
Laender <- as.matrix(read.csv('path/file.csv',row.names=1,check.names=F));
df <- as.matrix(read.csv('path/file1.csv',row.names=1,check.names=F));
```

Then you would be able to omit the `as.matrix()` calls in the `tapply()` line, so it would become very concise: `tapply(df,Laender,mean);`.

---

Also, just to add one thing, if you did want to compute averages manually, there's a better way than looping through every cell: You can compare `Laender` against a state name to get a logical matrix, then index `df` with that to get the values for that state, and then take the mean:

```
mean(df[Laender=='BadenW']);
## [1] 10.35327
```

And in fact, combining the above with `c()`, `unique()`, and `sapply()`, we can accomplish the entire task without the help of `tapply()`:

```
sapply(unique(c(as.matrix(Laender))),function(s) mean(df[Laender==s]));
##       Sachsen   MVorpommern        Bremen        RPfalz       SAnhalt
##      10.87170      10.66969      10.57423      10.54924      10.49251
##   Brandenburg     SHolstein        Bayern        BadenW   NRWestfalen
##      11.09401      10.51719      10.30455      10.35327      11.09304
##        Hessen        Berlin Niedersachsen    Thueringen      Saarland
##      10.55788      10.80498      10.90239      10.52608      10.48975
##       Hamburg
##      11.05088
```

Comment: tapply() is exactly what I needed, thank you! I would recommend to change the last part of the main code though:

tapply(as.matrix(df[1:6,1:6]),as.matrix(Laender[1:6,1:6]),mean)

At first sight it was a bit confusing to see the values under the states without any correlation to the depicted tables.